# I have a problem when I run the app for the first time, when I click on the text fields, the app restarts

Tags: flutter

I have a problem when I run the app for the first time, when I click on the text fields, the app restarts, but when I exit the app and login again and click on the text fields again, the app does not restart. #80924

this video of my issue in below
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WGrhR.jpg

Comment: Are there any errors you see in the console?

Comment: W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 5015): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 5015): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 5015): getTextAfterCursor on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 5015): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 5015): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 5015): beginBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
W/IInputConnectionWrapper( 5015): getTextBeforeCursor on inactive InputConnection